# Check connectivity between Kamailio and Database

Tags: kamailio

How I can check connectivity between Kamailio and database server on Kamailio?
When Kamailio has connection problems to the database due to network or something else, I want to create some logic to handle these cases. I was looking for a similar functionality, but have not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can eventually do a simple query from configuration file using sql_query(...) from sqlops and if it fails, very likely there is something wrong with the database server. For example:

```
if(!sql_query("SELECT NOW()")) { ... }
```